# I have this error in selenium : (Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

when I use this function and try to do anything with driver like getting a title or anything else it gives me this error:
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)

note: I use this function to close ads in other tabs

```
def CloseNewWindows(driver):

    MainWindow = driver.current_window_handle
    Windows = driver.window_handles
    for window in Windows:
        driver.switch_to_window(window)
        if MainWindow != driver.current_window_handle:
            driver.close()

    print(driver.title)
```

Comment: Why are you using `driver` in some places, and `self.driver` in other places?

Comment: When you call `driver.close()`, does focus automatically switch to another window?  Or do you need to explicitly call `switch_to_window()`?

Comment: So, you are showing us code that works that is unrelated to the code that fails?  Show us the code that fails, and the exact line that gets the error.